# Is there a dummy pointer type as function argument in golang

Tags: go

Is there a placeholder-like dummy pointer type which will allow not to make extra variable for rows.Scan() when number of columns mismatch with number of args in rows.Scan() in golang ?

```
rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT 1, 2, 3`)
for rows.Next() {
    var c1 int
    var c2 int
    // panic (number of arguments mismatch)
    err = rows.Scan(&c1, &c2)
    // syntax error
    err = rows.Scan(&c1, &c2, _)
    // Scan error on column index 2: destination not a pointer
    err = rows.Scan(&c1, &c2, nil)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `&_`?

Comment: yes, `cannot use '_' as a value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.

You must pass a pointer to a value. You can, of course, ignore that value after it's populated by Scan:

```
dummy := new(T) // creates a pointer to a zero-value object of type T
err := rows.Scan(dummy)
```